# Const char * vs const wchar_t* (concatenation)

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation, strcpy, strcat

which is the best way to concat?

```
const char * s1= "\nInit() failed: ";
const char * s2 = "\n";
char buf[100];
strcpy(buf, s1);
strcat(buf, initError);
strcat(buf, s2);
wprintf(buf);
```

It gives error. What should be the correct way?

Thanks.

Comment: What is initError? Plus you must use printf if you are dealing with char. Is initError of type wchar_t?

Comment: Are you looking for `wcstombs`?

Comment: initError is also of type const char *

Comment: if i use printf and fprintf. it's all fine. but what should i do if i want to use wprintf and fwprintf?

Comment: If you want to use `wprintf` and such, you use wide characters, meaning `wchar_t` rather than `char` and corresponding functions.  Functions that run on certain datatypes won't work when given different datatypes as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct way is:

```
std::string msg = std::string("Init() Failed ") + initError + "\n";
std::cout<<msg;
```

or

```
std::cout<<"Init() Failed "<<initError<<"\n";
```

Comment: @Azodious: If you want to use the c-functions, use `msg.c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your big problem is that you're mixing data types.  Use either `char` and associated functions or `wchar` and associated functions.  If you need to mix them, use a conversion function.  This makes no more sense than trying to pass a float to a function needing a string.  (The compiler should be able to catch both problems, since the declaration of `wprintf` is something like `int wprintf(const wchar_t *, ...)`.)

Another, more minor, issue is that `printf` and such are not the right functions to print out general strings, since if there are any percent signs in the strings you'll get undefined behavior.  Use `printf("%s",...)` or `puts(...)` or related functions.

And, since this is C++, you'd be much better off using the `std::string` class.  It isn't perfect, but it's far better than C-style strings.

Also, telling us what the error is would help.  You haven't even told us whether it's a compiler error or a run-time error.